# ASP.NET Display money in Designer properly formatted

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net

In code behind I have property which looks like this:

```
private decimal _myCodeBehindVariable;
public decimal myCodeBehindVariable
{
    get { return _myCodeBehindVariable; }
    set { _myCodeBehindVariable = value; }
}
```

In designer I am getting a value of this variable like this:

```
<%=myCodeBehindVariable%>
```

However I need to property format it with $ and . so it will look something like this: $35.99

Planning to use accounting.js for this (http://josscrowcroft.github.io/accounting.js/) and I can do this to display the amount in an asp label

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"><%=myCodeBehindVariable%></asp:Label>
```

The thing is how do I apply js I need something like

```
accounting.formatMoney(<%=myCodeBehindVariable%>); <- this does not work!
```

I decided to go with formatting money with code behind and displaying in it. Changed my code to this:

```
    private string _myCodeBehindVariable;
    public string myCodeBehindVariable
    {
        get { return _myCodeBehindVariable; }
        set { _myCodeBehindVariable = value; }
    }
```

Later in the code ...
            decimal theAmount = -9999.77m;

```
        myCodeBehindVariable = theAmount.ToString("C2", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"));
```

This way I get to keep <%=myCodeBehindVariable%> in designer.

Comment: So <%=myCodeBehindVariable%> renders correctly when in the asp:Label by itself, but when it's in Javascript it doesn't? What do you see when you view the source?

Comment: @TeamTam That is the thing I am not sure how to apply javascript before setting a value on a label. Later on I want to display bunch of labels I don't know how many it will be determined at run time but each label value must be formatted with javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a greater understanding of the context, these are the approaches I would consider.

1. If the labels are determined at run-time, this implies some sort of data binding. In which case, you may need a data binding expression `<%# ... %>` instead of the inline expression `<%= ... %>`.
2. If you are using JavaScript anyway to display what you need, is the ASP.NET label really necessary (i.e. `<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server">`)? This would just get rendered as `<div>` in HTML ultimately. So if you don't specifically need the label in your code-behind, I would look at ditching it, getting ASP.NET to spit out the values you need, just get JavaScript to do the presentation logic of formatting the decimal with `<div>` as the HTML placeholder. The other advantage of this approach is that it will make your page more lightweight and avoid any ASP.NET ViewState nastiness.
3. Alternatively, if you don't specifically need to use that particular JavaScript library, then perhaps a simple `myCodeBehindVariable.ToString("C3", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"))` in pure C# would do the trick. You could do this on either the .aspx page or the code-behind.